# How quickly could my Tor hidden service be deanonymized if I run it on the same machine as a relay?

Tags: anonymity

Suppose I'm already running a Tor relay, and I want to run a hidden service for a little while. I know it's bad to run both on the same Internet connection (because of timing attacks), but it would be really convenient, and I'm not going to keep the hidden service around all that long.

How long could I safely run my hidden service there? That is, how long - roughly - would it take for someone to deanonymize the service if I ran it on the same machine as a relay?

Comment: @BenN don't you think that it would be better if you asked this question on tor.se?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can run it in a single Tor instance with no problem. The de-anonymizing risk exists only if you're running it in a separate instance, and - the service descriptor is *very hard* to pinpoint/map to your HS.

Comment: The deanonymization seems to be allowed by the patterns in *connection* uptime. [This guy](https://cybermashup.com/2013/09/04/dont-run-a-tor-router-and-a-hidden-service-from-the-same-connection/) was able to deanonymize several hidden services without too much trouble. It'll definitely happen eventually if I run in this configuration, I'm just wondering how long.

Comment: @BenN his attack seems to be broken if the server descriptor will be turned private